# Time step agnostic simulations - is there a general rule?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, simulation

I'm working on a videogame where part of the logic involves increasing a value each render frame (a render frame is equivalent to a simulation step where the result is drawn on the screen).

Frames can have varying time steps between them, commonly named "delta time".

I am wondering if there is a general approach to determining whether the expression that updates the value is "pinned" to real time, meaning that running one frame with delta time `x` is equivalent to running `n` frames with delta times adding up to `x`.

I have [thought about this](https://marcospereira.me/2023/11/15/frame-rate-independent-lerp/) extensively for a few days now, but haven't reached the clean generalization I think would be possible to reach.

Say every frame we update value `a` with the following expression:

`a = a + (b - a) * d`

This is a commonly used formula for linear interpolation, where `b` is a constant that can be interpreted as a target value, and `d` is another constant between 0 and 1 that represents the fraction of distance to cover.

Now as you can see in the link I shared above I have calculated that to do this independently from frame rate one has to replace the factor `d` with an expression that involves `delta_time`:

`a = a + (b - a) * (1 - d^delta_time)`

I did this by expressing this process as a recursive sequence:

```
S(0) = a
S(n) = S(n-1) + (b - S(n-1)) * d
```

Then making it non-recursive (I don't think there's a standard approach for this, just expanding the expression and looking for patterns such as series with known formulas for the sum of the first `n` elements).

Once I reached a non-recursive form, I replaced `n` with `t / delta_time`, as the number of frames elapsed is equivalent to time elapsed divided by the time between frames. Then, I introduced `delta_time` into the expression in order to cancel it out, and translated that change into a change in the `d` constant.

I am not happy with this approach however.

I am now trying to formulate the problem in some other way, seeing if it gives me some clues as to a clean generalization.

What I'm looking for is a simple rule, a way to express that:

Given an expression `S(delta_time)` which calculates how much to increase a value by each frame, an increase of `x` in `delta_time` should be equivalent to running one iteration with `delta_time = x`.

I would also be interested in a solution that would provide assurance in terms of varying time step between frames - so not just agnostic to different `delta_time` over `n` frames, but agnostic to any `delta_time` between each subsequent frame. I think this may have no importance mathematically, but I'm not sure.

Could someone help elucidate me? I feel I'm at the edge of my mathematical ability.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Zeno strikes again!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox) Atalanta will never reach the end of her path.

The problem is that you are slicing the ratio of distance travelled to total distance, not to the time increment. This is **not** a sensible way to simulate physical movement:

> `a = lerp(a, b, d)`

Or to put it more precisely:

`CurrentPosition = PreviousPosition + (Destination - PreviousPosition) * RatioOfDistance`

where you are treating `RatioOfDistance` as if it were a constant of the motion. It. Is. Not!

What *is* a constant of motion (and your changing frames do represent a "motion" of some sort) depends on what you are simulating.

- The simplest situation is simulating something moving at a fixed speed. Speed - ratio of distance travelled divided by the time increment - is a constant of the motion.

For this situation, at the *start* of the motion, you calculate

`DistanceIncrementPerSecond = (Destination - OriginalPosition) / TotalTimeInSeconds`

Then you calculate

`DistanceIncrementPerFrame = DistanceIncrementPerSecond / FramesPerSecond`

And your "recursion" becomes

`CurrentPosition = PreviousPosition + DistanceIncrementPerFrame`

Of course, this can result in jerky motions as things suddenly start moving a full speed and then suddenly stop. So you might want to make acceleration the constant:

`CurrentDistanceIncrement = PreviousDistanceIncrement + SpeedIncrementPerFrame CurrentPosition = PreviousPosition + CurrentDistanceIncrement`

This may still be too jerky. Usually one more level suffices to appear smooth:

`CurrentSpeedIncrement = PreviousSpeedIncrement + AccelerationIncrementPerFrame CurrentDistanceIncrement = PreviousDistanceIncrement + SpeedIncrement CurrentPosition = PreviousPosition + CurrentDistanceIncrement`

Where

`AccelerationIncrementPerFrame = AccelerationIncrementPerSecond / FramesPerSecond`

and `AccelerationIncrementPerSecond` is the constant you change abruptly to control the movement. But in any case, you do your modelling at a fixed time increment such as seconds, and convert by frames per second only in calculating the increments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think this is a bit too specific to linear interpolation - I just gave that as an example, but I'm interested in a more general abstract reasoning for any kind of iterative process (something that runs every simulation step)

There are a lot of things at play here, such as expressing the problem as a recursive sequence (closer to the code) or trying to convert the code into a non-recursive form that is parameterized by absolute time

Comment: You've missed the point. The problem was you were ignoring the actual physics you were trying to implement to play around with formulas and algorithms you didn't understand. That will never get you anywhere. You start with the physics. Frame rate is just a time unit, but since it varies, you choose a fixed time unit and do any conversions with time parameters, not whatever arbitrary parameters you decided to put in your function you love to call "recursion" even though it really is doing iterations (difference: Recursion calls itself repeatedly. Interations are called by others repeatedly.)

Comment: But the underlying maths here don't have to be grounded in physics in any way. I since learned the property of being "frame rate independent" is equivalent to "flow" in mathematics

Comment: The concept of "flow" in mathematics was developed *precisely* to be used in physics to describe the eponymous physical process. And since your purpose is to display images on a screen sequentially in a way that viewers will automatically understand, you are tapping into the human brain's ability to interpret those changes. This ability is grounded in physics. If your images do not obey physical laws, they will either be not understood, or will be perceived as unnatural. You VERY MUCH need to ground your changes in physics. How in the world you got the idea this wasn't necessary is beyond me.